# Applying np.where when iterating through an array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a folder with 100 repetition files. Each file is an array with 300 values. I use the glob function to combine these all into a single array of arrays. 
I would like to create a new array of arrays (i.e., a subset of the original) with the criterion being only the lists where the last value in each list is greater than 1.  
I think np.where is the best way to achieve this but I am not sure how to apply it when iterating through an array of arrays. So far I have:

```
reps=sorted(glob.glob('C:/Users/Repetitions/*')
outbreaks=[]

for r in reps:
    prevalence=np.loadtxt(r,delimiter=',')
    
    if np.where(prevalence[-1] > 1):
        outbreaks.append(prevalence)
```

This doesn't work as I expected it wouldn't -all of the arrays get added to the new outbreaks list. How do I change the second to last line to achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: `np.where` is just a tool to find the indices of non-zero values in an array.  In fact the preferred usage is `np.nonzero(...)`.  And do read the docs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not need `np.where` if I understand the question correctly. You can use:

```
for r in reps:
    prevalence=np.loadtxt(r,delimiter=',')
    
    if prevalence[-1] > 1:
        outbreaks.append(prevalence)
```

However, this creates a list of array and if you need array of arrays simply do:

```
outbreaks = np.array(outbreaks)
```

But I don't see a point in having an array of arrays. You probably are better off with your original list of arrays.

Comment: Thank you! I believe you are right after trying it out. I was trying to make it more difficult than it needed to be!

Comment: @Noelle Glad it helped.